# Is using call_soon_threadsafe and GLib.idle_add together the correct way to safely call GTK code from asyncio, or is it overkill?

Tags: python, gtk, glib, pygi

I have an application that runs in an asyncio event loop and I want to add a feature that interacts with my Gnome Shell, in particular sending a notification. Since GTK has its own (incompatible, I understand) event loop, I decided to throw the `Gio.Application` into a background thread. My question is about the appropriate way to run "GTK code" from my asyncio event loop, for example creating the notification and firing it from my Application.

Take the following code, I am scheduling the "add notification" method with the following line of code:

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().call_soon_threadsafe(GLib.idle_add,
    app.add_notification, "You have a new email")
```

This "works", but I wonder if both `call_soon_threadsafe` and `idle_add` are redundant. It also works if I simply call

```
app.add_notification("You have a new email")
```

from my coroutine, however the [PyGObject documentation](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/threading.html#threads) suggests this is thread-unsafe. What's the recommended safe approach? Below is a minimal proof of concept launching a notification from an asyncio coroutine.

```py
import asyncio
import threading

import gi
gi.require_version('Gio', '2.0')
from gi.repository import Gio, GLib


class ThreadsafeEvent(asyncio.Event):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self._loop is None:
            self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def set(self):
        self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(super().set)

    def clear(self):
        self._loop.call_soon_threadsafe(super().clear)

class Application(Gio.Application):
    APP_ID = "org.something"

    def __init__(self, activated_event: threading.Event):
        flags = Gio.ApplicationFlags.FLAGS_NONE
        super().__init__(application_id=Application.APP_ID, flags=flags)
        self.activated_event = activated_event
        self.activated = False

    def do_activate(self):
        if not self.activated:
            self.hold()
            self.activated = True
            self.activated_event.set()

    def add_notification(self, message):
        note = Gio.Notification.new(message)
        self.send_notification(None, note)


async def main():
    event = ThreadsafeEvent()
    app = Application(event)

    def start(app: Application):
        app.register()
        app.run()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=start, args=(app,))
    thread.setDaemon(True)
    thread.start()

    try:
        # When the event is set, we know the Application
        # is activated and safe to send notifications through
        await asyncio.wait_for(event.wait(), 10)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print('Timed out before App received its activation.')

    asyncio.get_event_loop().call_soon_threadsafe(GLib.idle_add,
        app.add_notification, "You have a new email")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(main(), loop=loop)
    loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Found the answer yourself?

Comment: No, however I've been using this pattern (both `call_soon_threadsafe` and `GLib.idle_add`) in my app for almost a year now and have noticed no issues. That said, usage is low enough that it's possible I've never organically run into threading issues.